# Check all child checkbox using parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click "Check all group 1", it should select its children only, but now it also selects "Check all group 2" items. How can I fix this?

**Code:**

```js
jQuery(".parentCheckAll").click(function(e) {
  jQuery("#" + jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr("id") + " .extended-checkboxes input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentCheckAll"> Check all group 1</div>
<div class="extended-checkboxes">
  <input name="" type="checkbox" item="" class="checkbox-meta" tabindex="1"><br />
  <input name="" type="checkbox" item="" class="checkbox-meta" tabindex="2">
</div>
</div>

<div class="parentCheckAll"> Check all group 2</div>
<div class="extended-checkboxes">
  <input name="" type="checkbox" item="" class="checkbox-meta" tabindex="3"><br />
  <input name="" type="checkbox" item="" class="checkbox-meta" tabindex="4">
</div>
```

Comment: _"it should selects their child only"_ There aren't any _child elements_

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you expect your code to actually do, but in order to achieve what you want, all you have to do is:

1. Get the element with class `extended-checkboxes` following the clicked element and
2. Select its `input` children.

Something like the following:

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
$(".parentCheckAll").click(function(e) {
  $(this.nextElementSibling).children("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentCheckAll"> Check all group 1</div>
<div class="extended-checkboxes">
  <input name="" type="checkbox" item="" class="checkbox-meta" tabindex="1"><br />
  <input name="" type="checkbox" item="" class="checkbox-meta" tabindex="2">
</div>

<div class="parentCheckAll"> Check all group 2</div>
<div class="extended-checkboxes">
  <input name="" type="checkbox" item="" class="checkbox-meta" tabindex="3">
  <br />
  <input name="" type="checkbox" item="" class="checkbox-meta" tabindex="4">
</div>
```

---

**Note:** From `jQuery 1.6` onwards, it is recommended to prefer [`prop`](https://api.jquery.com/prop)
instead of [`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr) when trying to check checkboxes *(See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397244/check-all-child-checkbox-using-parent-class/48397296#comment83782574_48397296))*.

Comment: [`.attr()` -> `.prop()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Andreas. I've cited you comment in the answer 